# Restart Jetty through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm new to Eclipse and Google App Engine development.

I am unable to refresh my localhost to display changes in my code. Clicking Run doesn't seem to rebuild it. I can't find the option to refresh the server in the Eclipse IDE to reflect the changes.

Refreshing the browser / clearing my browser cache doesn't work, so it's clearly server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should stop launched application -> red rectangle in console window. After that click at the top menu Project -> Clean. Choose your project and set check box "Start build immediatly" if it present. Then run again your project and see your changes.